# Filtering a data frame with values in a column

Tags: r, dataframe

My data is the longitude and latitude and depth of earthquakes.

I am trying to create a data frame with only the long and lat for depths greater than 70.

How would I do this?

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Eba.png)

Comment: `subset(ex.data, depth>70)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
 filter(depth > 70)
```